# Seed a Role and assign Permissions with Data Seeder on ABP Framework

Tags: abp

I'm working with the ABP Framework and need a way to seed a Role on migrations like the admin Role. I've accomplished this by injecting the `IIdentityRoleRepository identityRoleRepository` in `IDataSeedContributor.cs` and using the `InsertAsync` method.

Now I want to assign permissions to this Role, the problem is that, following the abp documentation tutorials, I defined the Permissions on the `Application.Contracts` module and **it isn't imported** in the `Domain` module where `IDataSeedContributor.cs` resides.
I tried defining another Seeder in the `Application.Contracts` Module but it doesn't find the `IIdentityRoleRepository` because it's defined in `Domain`.

The framework follows the following hierarchy:
[image: ABP hierrachy]

Following this, I tried defining the Seeder in the `Application` module but it does not execute when running `DbMigrator`.

The shortest solution I found is including `Application.Contracts` in the `Domain.csproj` but I think it goes against the DDD of the framework. Is there a way to define a Seeder in other modules or have access to the `RoleRepository` in `Application.Contracts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do in this case is to define the constant permissions in the Domain.Shared layer and you can use it in Application.Contracts and in Domain, seeders are normally used in the domain layer

Comment: Simple solution, worked great and I didn't have to make changes in the project structure. Thanks